# What is the diferences between pure Wordpress theme and Woocommerce theme?

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I've made some WP simple sites, so I already know how to create a WP theme, but now I want to create simple e-commerce, with woocommerce, so, I need to know how to create woocommerce themes? Is there much diferences from a simple WP theme? And can you provide some links and directions where I can study it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "WooCommerce themes", only WordPress themes that eventually offer CSS styling for WooCommerce pages and layout elements, and, maybe, customize them by overwriting the WooCommerce templates.

This is a good place to start: https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/

Also, take a look at the "official" WooCommerce theme right from the creators: https://woocommerce.com/storefront/

Apart from these, the internet is brimming with resources: https://www.google.com/search?q=developing+woocommerce+themes